# Auto-populating a form on an external site

Tags: auto-populate

I'm writing an app that sends emails to your local congressman. Is there a way to auto-populate the form on the government website using information sent to my app? For example, if a user of my app provides their personal information and a personal message to their congressman, is there a way to auto-populate the forms on the government website?

This is my local congressman's website: https://campbell.house.gov/email-me/
The automation process would need to autopopulate the zip code (92618), press the "go to form" button, then auto-populate the email form (including selecting a state and topic from drop down menus), and press send email. Is this possible? Are there cross-scripting constraints that prevent this? If not, is there some way of getting the Congressman's direct email address from their website? I want to make it as easy as possible to contact your local Congressman. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that they don't have any safe guards in place for this you could actually just create a POST request that posts your data straight to https://campbell.house.gov/email-me/ as that is the action of the form.

You can try this out by copying the form from the webpage to your own html-file, fill it out and then submit the form.

Just make sure to use the whole url to the action (including the domain name) in the action.